# Com quais bancos de dados o Apache Atlas é compatível?

Tags: sql, nosql, hadoop, big-data

O apache Atlas tem compatibilidade com quais bancos de dados noSQL e SQL 
estou fazendo um trabalho, e não consegui achar nada sobre

Answer (score 0):

Pelo [o que entendi](http://atlas.apache.org/InstallationSteps.html), o Apache Atlas usa o [HBase](https://hbase.apache.org) e apenas ele, uma vez que o Apache Atlas usa Hadoop e o banco de dados do Hadoop é o HBase. Você pode escolher entre usar um HBase externo ou usar um HBase *embedded*:

> Above will build Atlas for an environment having functional HBase and Solr instances.

E:

> To create Apache Atlas package that includes HBase and Solr, build with the embedded-hbase-solr profile